# Debian on HP Gen9 — most recent hpssacli appears to be too old

Tags: monitoring, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

I've installed a recent Debian 10 Buster system on to the server, which is HPE DL360 Gen9. It has P440ar adapter, which works with the "new" `hpsa` driver. As far as I remember, RAIDs were configured with built-in "pre-boot" GUI utility. All firmwares were updated to their most recent versions, so I believe that utility was also most recent version.

Now I have to set up RAID state monitoring to a Zabbix server.

`hpsa` arrays are managed with the `hpssacli` utility (the old `hpacucli` supports a `cciss` driver, which isn't applicable for me). I have a wrapper script which runs from Zabbix agent, it is able to discover and query state of each array in the system, that script just calls `hpssacli`, parses and adapts its output for Zabbix. I've doing that for ages.

On this newly set up system, I have a trouble. I tried a HPe's own [SDR MCP](https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/project/mcp/) repo, it doesn't support buster yes (HPe is notoriusly slow in updating their repos), so I just found a most recent `hpssacli` deb and installed it. It appeared to be `hpssacli-2.40-13.0_amd64.deb`, dated 2016-06-28 17:55.

However, when I tried to run it, it says: my array was created with more recent version of utility and my version is too old to manage it:

```
root@vh3:~# wget https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/mcp/pool/non-free/hpssacli-2.40-13.0_amd64.deb
--2019-11-25 14:13:38--  https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/mcp/pool/non-free/hpssacli-2.40-13.0_amd64.deb
Распознаётся downloads.linux.hpe.com (downloads.linux.hpe.com)… 15.249.152.85
Подключение к downloads.linux.hpe.com (downloads.linux.hpe.com)|15.249.152.85|:443... соединение установлено.
HTTP-запрос отправлен. Ожидание ответа… 200 OK
Длина: 8237034 (7,9M)
Сохранение в: «hpssacli-2.40-13.0_amd64.deb»

hpssacli-2.40-13.0_amd64.deb                    100%[====================================================================================================>]   7,85M   394KB/s    за 22s     

2019-11-25 14:14:01 (363 KB/s) - «hpssacli-2.40-13.0_amd64.deb» сохранён [8237034/8237034]

root@vh3:~# ls
hpssacli-2.40-13.0_amd64.deb
root@vh3:~# dpkg -i hpssacli-2.40-13.0_amd64.deb 
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета hpssacli.
(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 57199 файлов и каталогов.)
Подготовка к распаковке hpssacli-2.40-13.0_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается hpssacli (2.40-13.0) …
Настраивается пакет hpssacli (2.40-13.0) …
Обрабатываются триггеры для man-db (2.8.5-2) …
root@vh3:~# hpssacli ctrl all show

Smart Array P440ar in Slot 0 (Embedded) 

APPLICATION UPGRADE REQUIRED: This controller has been configured with a more
                              recent version of software.
                              To prevent data loss, configuration changes to
                              this controller are not allowed.
                              Please upgrade to the latest version to be able
                              to continue to configure this controller.
```

While this doesn't seem to prevent my script to monitor a controller state, I also want to be able to manage it from the operating system, to be able to add drives and create more arrays without stopping a system in the future.

I also tried to use [hwraid.le-vert.net](http://hwraid.le-vert.net/) repo, but there is no `hpssacli` utility (it only has `hpacucli`, at least in buster).

What I supposed to do? Where to find this "latest" version and how to find out which version I need?

Comment: I have installed on my stretch system `ssacli` package version 3.30-13.0, which replaces `hpssacli`. Try that instead. I used this apt sources.list line: `deb http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/mcp stretch/current non-free`

Comment: Yes, this version works. Thanks! Also, please, format that as an answer, I'll accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hpssacli` package has been superceded by the `ssacli` package.

At the moment there is no specific version for Debian buster, but the stretch package should work just fine. To be able to install it with `apt` etc., create a file e.g. `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mcp.list` and insert the following lines into that file:

```
# Hewlett Packard Enterprise (HPE) Management Component Pack 
deb https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/mcp stretch/current non-free
```

You also need to add the public key for that repository:

```
curl https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/hpePublicKey2048_key1.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Now update the local indexes:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

(Or use `apt` or `aptitude`, whatever you're used to.)

Now you can install the `ssacli` package with e.g. `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install ssacli
```

For reference, this is documented at https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/project/mcp/

Comment: Thanks for this! BTW you should really pull that GPG key via `https://`